# How to store Angular translation strings in an array

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I use angular-translate to localise my app and display my string inside brackets `{{"TEA_BREAK" | translate}}` . Now, I want to store those strings `{{"TEA_BREAK" | translate}}` inside an array:

```
array = [ "{{'TEA_BREAK' | translate}}", "{{'TEA2_BREAK' | translate}}"];
```

Obviously that doesn't work. I did try different variations, with brackets, without brackets etc. Nothing works. I wonder what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: it's translate filter and filter should be only used in view. Why you put it in array like that ?

Comment: @SherlockedNguyen I need to store and manipulate those string with other data. Obviously I should get this data back from web service but for now it's not an option.

Comment: @Pawel_K even if you need keep them as array, you don't need the redundant part of the string looking at the elements in your array. for instance, {{ blah | translate }}.

Comment: Oh I completely agree, but the question is in what format store them in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use $filter service to translate these text.

Inject $filter service

```
function MyController($filter)
```

Then translate your text like this:

```
array.push($filter('translate')('TEA_BREAK'));
```